# Insert a component above layouts in nuxt

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to render a component only once (as soon as the page loads), but the component re-renders everytime the layout changes. Is there a way to declare a component above the layouts ? letś say, in the root component ?

Comment: Isn't the default layout enough? Everything should be wrapped in this one.

Comment: I don't think so, because i have other layouts on the same project. When i leave the default layout to any other, the component must be rendered again.

What i'm trying to achieve is, the component renders and stays on the screen, when the user closes it, it will not appear anymore, no matter the layout.

Comment: It's not very clear. Do you have a visual example, some code or a mode in-depth example of the actual component and it's functionality?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for taking this long. This article have helped me achieve what i wanted.
https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/